# Add dot notation to React.createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider this:

```
const Comp = React.createElement("div", {
    className: someClassName,
    // ... other props
})
```

And inside JSX:

```
return <div>{Comp}</div>
```

I like to add `motion` (from Framer-Motion library) to the `div` from `createElement` in dot notation, like this (JSX example):

```
<motion.div />
```

How do I can achieve the same result with `React.createElement`?

To be clear: I need to add `motion` to the `Comp` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

> createElement()
>
> React.createElement(
> type,
> [props],
> [...children]
> )
>
> Create and return a new React element of the given type. The type argument can be either a tag name string (such as 'div' or 'span'), a **React component type (a class or a function)**, or a React fragment type.

Therefore, instead of 'div' string, use a react compoment function or class, which, in Your case would be `motion.div`.

```js
const Comp = React.createElement(motion.div, {
    className: someClassName,
    // ... other props
})
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: @MáriusRak Is it possible to add `motion` to the resulting `{Comp}` component inside JSX? Because I'm creating elements with `createElement` conditionally, and sometimes it is `div`, and sometimes is `p` and so on... and I like to apply `motion` just once (possibly, the best place for it will be inside JSX)

Comment: Why are You not using jsx notation? And what is the `motion`? Your question is still unclear.